# How do you stop antler screen keyboard from opening?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, desktop, archlinux

The screen keyboard pops up in Catfish and some other programs.  It obscures part of the desktop and will not close without a SIGKILL.

Is there some way to stop this obnoxious (to me) behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

① To make the keyboard disappear from screen kill antler processes.

② To stop it appearing in a session, kill caribou processes.

③ To stop in future sessions, remove caribou from start-up processes.

Comment: Any details on ③? For me, caribou does not appear in `/etx/xdg/autostart` nor in `gnome-session-properties`, but it continues to start.

Answer (score 0):

Antler is a part of the Caribou-antler package, and is listed as "caribou" in the Archlinux extra repository.

`pacman -Qii` lists `caribou` as a dependency of gnome shell, but removing caribou can be done without apparent problems by using the command:`sudo pacman -Rdd caribou`

To avoid the caribou package from being updated or re-installed, add this line to `/etc/pacman.conf`.

```
IgnorePkg   = caribou
```

Eventually, gnome-shell will be updated in the repository,  When gnome-shell is updated in the repository, the upgrade will fail because of the now ignored caribou package with this message:

```
resolving dependencies...
warning: ignoring package caribou-n.n.nn-n
warning: cannot resolve "caribou", a dependency of "gnome-shell"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      gnome-shell

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N]
```

Select `y` and enter to allow other packages to be upgraded.

Then force the gnome-shell upgrade with this command:

```
sudo pacman -Sdd gnome-shell
```

Your system will now be fully upgraded.

To undo this change, simply delete or make a comment of the `IgnorePkg   = caribou` line in `/etc/pacman.conf`, then update your system with pacman.